# Unable to find wrapper "gs" using Laravel in Google App Engine

Tags: laravel, google-app-engine, laravel-5

I'm trying to deploy a Laravel 5.2 project to google app engine.

The deployment works but when I'm opening the application in the browser I get the following error:

```
PHP message: PHP Fatal error: Uncaught ErrorException: file_exists(): Unable to find the wrapper &quot;gs&quot; - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP? in /srv/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php:13958
```

The `app.yaml` looks like this:

```
runtime: php72

handlers:
  - url: /*
    script: auto
    secure: always
    redirect_http_response_code: 301

automatic_scaling:
  target_cpu_utilization: 0.65
  min_instances: 1
  max_instances: 1
  min_pending_latency: 30ms
  max_pending_latency: automatic

env_variables:
  APP_ENV: local
  APP_DEBUG: true
  APP_KEY: my-key
  APP_STORAGE: gs://my-bucket
  CACHE_DRIVER: file
  SESSION_DRIVER: file
  QUEUE_DRIVER: sync
```

I configured my application to use a google storage bucket as my storage directory since the standard environment is a read only filesystem.

I added a `php.ini` file to the root of my project whith the following contents:

```
google_app_engine.allow_include_gs_buckets="#default#, my-bucket"
```

What can be the cause of this problem?